# Zero-One argument Constructor

Tags: c++

```
const int max_sku_length = 7;
const int max_unit_length = 10;
const int max_name_length = 75;
const double TRate = 0.13;
char m_type;
char m_sku[max_sku_length +1];
char m_unit[max_unit_length + 1];
char* m_name;
int m_Cquantity;
int m_Nquantity;
double m_price;
bool m_status;

Product()
{
    this->m_sku[0] = '\0';
    this->m_name = nullptr;
    this->m_price = 0;
    this->m_Cquantity = 0;
    this->m_status = false;
    this->m_Nquantity = 0;
    this->m_type = '\0';
    this->m_unit[0] = '\0';
}
```

I am new to C++. I need to create a

•   Zero-One argument Constructor

This constructor optionally receives a character that identifies the product type. The default value is ‘N’. This function

- stores the character receives in an instance variable
- sets the current object to a safe recognizable empty state.

I constructed zero argument constructor, but I am not really sure how to do Zero-one argument constructor. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you try googling `c++ default arguments` and reading one of the plethora of results, which explain how to create default arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default argument.

```
Product::Product (char productType = 'N') {
    // your stuff
}
```

Comment: But, like I mean do I need to create 2 separate constructors or it's just one constructor working for both cases?

Comment: @Azal It's one constructor that takes one argument. The argument has a default, which means if you don't specify it, it is automatically set to some value. You should learn more about default arguments in C++. Google is a good way to start.

Comment: Product(char ptype = 'N');

Comment: Product::Product(char t)
 {
  
  this->m_type = t;
  this->m_sku[0] = '\0';
  this->m_name = nullptr;
  this->m_price = 0;
  this->m_Cquantity = 0;
  this->m_status = false;
  this->m_Nquantity = 0;
  this->m_type = '\0';
  this->m_unit[0] = '\0';
 }

Comment: @Azal almost. You are assigning to `m_type` twice. Once to take the input value, which is correct, but then you overwrite it with `'\0'`, which is wrong. Get rid of the second assignment

Comment: @Azal There is really no point in using `this->` when accessing other class members from a member function. You should also learn about constructor member initialization lists.